# Android Studio 0.8.6 does NOT automatically sync with gradle files

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I don't know what I have done or what has happened. But my project has suddenly stopped to sync my project with the gradle files. So every time I run the app my changes aren't there. I have to go to Tools > Android > Sync project with gradle files before every time I run the app. I didn't need to before.

Any ideas of how I can fix this?

EDIT: I've done the usual stuff like rebuild and clean the project. without any change.

And for people who just vote close please specify why somewhere so the person you vote on can either improve the question or at least understand why it should be closed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can always try to "Open Project" from quick start instead of recently open (point at actual build.gradle instead of directory) and choose "Delete Existing Project and Import"
2. Check in preferences that you did not by any accident un-checked "Synchronize files on frame activation" in Preferences > IDE Settings > General > Synchronization

Comment: thanks! point 1 worked. Any idea why "Open Project" works and not "Recently Opened"? Recent is the one I've always used before.

Comment: I do not know reason, but from my experience this usually happens when I haveto jump between branches with larger differences in code base

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invalidating your caches..File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: What is your gradle version??Show your build.gradle file